# How to stream video (motion jpeg) using falcon server?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, video-streaming, falconframework

**Desired output**

Input: Camera feed using OpenCV or from a REST camera url. **(Not a concern for this question)**

Output: Streaming jpeg images after doing some OpenCV processing

---

So far I have done the following based on `Falcon` [tutorial](https://falcon.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/tutorial.html#serving-images)

Input: Image file as a POST request

Output: GET request endpoint with the path to the image

```
import mimetypes
import os
import re
import uuid
import cv2
import io
import falcon
from falcon import media
import json
import msgpack

class Collection(object):

    def __init__(self, image_store):
        self._image_store = image_store

    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        # TODO: Modify this to return a list of href's based on
        # what images are actually available.
        doc = {
            'images': [
                {
                    'href': '/images/1eaf6ef1-7f2d-4ecc-a8d5-6e8adba7cc0e.png'
                }
            ]
        }

        resp.data = msgpack.packb(doc, use_bin_type=True)
        resp.content_type = falcon.MEDIA_MSGPACK
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

    def on_post(self, req, resp):
        name = self._image_store.save(req.stream, req.content_type)
        # Unnecessary Hack to read the saved file in OpenCV
        image = cv2.imread("images/" + name)
        new_image = do_something_with_image(image)
        _ = cv2.imwrite("images/" + name, new_image)
        resp.status = falcon.HTTP_201
        resp.location = '/images/' + name


class Item(object):

    def __init__(self, image_store):
        self._image_store = image_store

    def on_get(self, req, resp, name):
        resp.content_type = mimetypes.guess_type(name)[0]
        resp.stream, resp.stream_len = self._image_store.open(name)


class ImageStore(object):

    _CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES = 4096
    _IMAGE_NAME_PATTERN = re.compile(
        '[0-9a-f]{8}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{12}\.[a-z]{2,4}$'
    )

    def __init__(self, storage_path, uuidgen=uuid.uuid4, fopen=io.open):
        self._storage_path = storage_path
        self._uuidgen = uuidgen
        self._fopen = fopen

    def save(self, image_stream, image_content_type):
        ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(image_content_type) # Issue with this code, Not returning the extension so hard coding it in next line
        ext = ".jpg"
        name = '{uuid}{ext}'.format(uuid=self._uuidgen(), ext=ext)
        image_path = os.path.join(self._storage_path, name)

        with self._fopen(image_path, 'wb') as image_file:
            while True:
                chunk = image_stream.read(self._CHUNK_SIZE_BYTES)
                if not chunk:
                    break

                image_file.write(chunk)

        return name

    def open(self, name):
        # Always validate untrusted input!
        if not self._IMAGE_NAME_PATTERN.match(name):
            raise IOError('File not found')

        image_path = os.path.join(self._storage_path, name)
        stream = self._fopen(image_path, 'rb')
        stream_len = os.path.getsize(image_path)
        return stream, stream_len


def create_app(image_store):
    api = falcon.API()
    api.add_route('/images', Collection(image_store))
    api.add_route('/images/{name}', Item(image_store))
    api.add_sink(handle_404, '')
    return api


def get_app():
    storage_path = os.environ.get('LOOK_STORAGE_PATH', './images')
    image_store = ImageStore(storage_path)
    return create_app(image_store)
```

The response is something like this:

> HTTP/1.1 201 Created
>
> Connection: close
>
> Date: Mon, 03 Dec 2018 13:08:14 GMT
>
> Server: gunicorn/19.7.1
>
> content-length: 0
>
> content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
>
> location: /images/e69a83ee-b369-47c3-8b1c-60ab7bf875ec.jpg

There are 2 problems with the above code:

1. I first get the data stream and save it in a file and then read it in OpenCV to do some other operations which is pretty overkill and should be easily fixed but I don't know how
2. This service does not stream the JPGs. All I have a GET request url which I can open in browser to see the image which is not ideal

So, how can I read `req.stream` data as numpy array? And more importantly what changes I need to make to stream images from this service?

> P.S. Apologies for a long post

Answer (score 4):

I have found a solution which works perfectly fine. For more on this check out [this beautiful code](http://www.chioka.in/python-live-video-streaming-example/).

```
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        image = camera.get_frame()
        new_image = do_something_with_image(image)
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', new_image)
        yield (b'--frame\r\n'
               b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + jpeg.tobytes() + b'\r\n\r\n')


class StreamResource(object):
    def on_get(self, req, resp):
        labeled_frame = gen(VideoCamera())
        resp.content_type = 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame'
        resp.stream = labeled_frame

def get_app():
    api = falcon.API()
    api.add_route('/feed', StreamResource())
    return api
```

Comment: it's working great for 30 seconds then i have to reload the client page to send a new request, seems like every request only works for 30 seconds, any idea how to fix this?